# Reading Source Folder in Sequence

Tags: python

I am trying to copy all images while renaming them from one folder to another. In the source folder its labelled as such.

Folder 1
Folder 2
...
...
Folder 100
Folder 101

When running the code, it copies from Folder 1, then jumps to Folder 100, Folder 101, etc, following the numerical sequence, instead of copying from Folder 2.

How do i make it such that it runs in sequence?

The current code looks like this.

```
current_file_index = 0

# Target file name length - length of the file name when copied over
tar_filename_len = 4

# Read source folders
src_folder_paths = os.listdir(src_folder_path)

for path in src_folder_paths:

    this_src_folder_path = os.path.join(src_folder_path, path)

# Get the contents of this source folder
    this_src_folder_files = os.listdir(this_src_folder_path)

    for filename in this_src_folder_files:

        this_file_path = os.path.join(this_src_folder_path, filename)
        
        tar_filename = str(current_file_index)
        len_diff = tar_filename_len - len(tar_filename)
        while len_diff > 0:
            tar_filename = '0%s' % tar_filename
            len_diff -= 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: what does your full directory structure look like, please try to include actual names of the files (not folders) and include the full directory structure of multiple folders (not necessarily 100 of them)

Comment: why dont you sort the  source folders and then iterate over it `src_folder_paths .sort()` ?

Comment: @AlbinPaul The folders are already sorted in the main directory. Its the naming sequence im trying to workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have printed the list which is sorted. You can use this.

```
import os
import re

src_folder_path = "testing"

current_file_index = 0

# Target file name length - length of the file name when copied over
tar_filename_len = 4

# Read source folders
src_folder_paths = os.listdir(src_folder_path)

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)',text) ]

src_folder_paths.sort(key=natural_keys)
print(src_folder_paths)

for path in src_folder_paths:

    this_src_folder_path = os.path.join(src_folder_path, path)

# Get the contents of this source folder
    this_src_folder_files = os.listdir(this_src_folder_path)

    for filename in this_src_folder_files:

        this_file_path = os.path.join(this_src_folder_path, filename)
        
        tar_filename = str(current_file_index)
        len_diff = tar_filename_len - len(tar_filename)
        while len_diff > 0:
            tar_filename = '0%s' % tar_filename
            len_diff -= 1
```